# ¿Cómo saber cual es la palabra mas larga de una cadena?

Tags: javascript, string

Sé que hacer esto debe de ser fácil, pero la verdad no se de que manera podría hacerlo, estaba trabajando en eso y estuve investigando pero me quede trabado. Me serviría de mucho si alguien me ayudara a terminar mi código. 
De antemano muchas gracias.

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var pp = str.split(" ");

  return str.length;
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Ya dividí el string en un array, lo unico que me falta es saber como medir cada palabra individualmente y saber cual es la que mide mas. Al principio se me ocurrió usar un ciclo for para ir de palabra en palabra pero después de eso me quede sin ideas, ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay varias formas de realizar esto:

```js
function buscaPalabraMasLarga(s) {
  palabra_mas_grande = ""
  palabras = s.replace(",", " ").split(" "); //replace usado para eliminar "," de las palabras.
  palabras.forEach(function(palabra){
  if (palabra.length > palabra_mas_grande.length){
       palabra_mas_grande = palabra
   };
  });
  return palabra_mas_grande 
};

alert( buscaPalabraMasLarga("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

otra forma :

```js
function longer(palabra_mas_grande , palabra) {
  return (palabra.length > palabra_mas_grande .length) ? palabra: palabra_mas_grande ;
}

function buscaPalabraMasLarga(s) {
    var palabras = s.replace(",", " ").split(" ");
    return palabras.reduce(longer);
}
alert( buscaPalabraMasLarga("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

De hecho lo estabas realizando correctamente y la idea que tenias era correcta, usar un ciclo y comparar la longitud:

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var pp = str.replace(",", " ").split(" ");
  palabra_mas_grande = ""
  pp.forEach(function(palabra){
  if (palabra.length > palabra_mas_grande.length){
       palabra_mas_grande = palabra
   };
  });
  return palabra_mas_grande;
}
alert("la palabra más grande es: " + findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: ¿Me podrias explicar la parte del ".forEach" por favor?

Comment: @RicardoA `forEach({})` indica que lo que está entre llaves se ejecutará para cada elemento dentro del `Array`

Comment: @NaCl , gracias! Después de separar las palabras de la cadena por cada palabra usando el forEach(), realiza una comparación buscando la de mayor longitud.

Comment: La verdad me gustaron mucho la primera y tercera opción, pero tengo una duda ¿De que manera es posible que puedas comparar "palabra.length" y "palabra_mas_grande.length" si según lo que veo en el código no tienen informacion dentro esas variables, si entiendo la mayoria de como funciona el código, pero la verdad al momento de aprender de programación se me complica mucho esa parte de entender la lógica del código, me lo podrías explicar, por favor?
Y muchas gracias @NaCl !!!

Comment: Ambas tiene valor, palabra_mas_grande.length al inicio es 0 ya que el contenido es un string vacio, "", en realidad si tiene valor. por ejemplo var variable = "", si obtienes la longitud mediante la propiedad length tendrás valor de 0, por ejemplo si var variable = "hola mundo"; aquí variable tendra una longitud de 10.

Comment: @Elenasys a simple ojo, los ejemplos poporcionados, creo que no toleran comas. un string por ejemplo: `"hola, mundo"` == `{ "hola,", "mundo" }` y nunca se cumple la condición de la palaba mas larga, o seria erronea.

Comment: @NaCl muy buen punto, agregué una modificación para soportar este caso que sería importante, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Que tal de esta manera?

```
function findLongestWord(str) {

  var length = 0, longestWord = "";
  var pp = str.split(" ");

  for(var i = 0 ; i < pp.length; i++)
    {
      if(pp[i].length > length){
          length = pp[i].length;
          longestWord = pp[i];
       }

    }

  return longestWord;
}

var b = findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");

alert(b);
```

http://jsbin.com/xucewaqefo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: hey no conocía este sitio http://jsbin.com/?html,js,output =0 gracias por el aporte!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Divides el texto en palabras, las recorres y comparas longitud.

```js
function longestWord(text) {
  const words = text.split(/ +/);
  let longest = words[0];
  words.map((word) => {
    if(word.length > longest.length) {
      longest = word;
    }
  });
  return longest;
}

console.log(longestWord("Italia venció por dos goles a cero a España por la Eurocopa 2016"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Respondí a [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/104710/29967) que un sus inicios era muy similar a esta. Luego aquella pregunta fue editada y modificada de forma sustancial, por lo que mi respuesta no tiene ningún sentido allí. Sin embargo, aquí podría tener utilidad, por lo cual la comparto aquí:

---

Hay un [interesante artículo con tres métodos para obtener la palabra más larga](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/three-ways-to-find-the-longest-word-in-a-string-in-javascript-a2fb04c9757c). Puedes optar por el que prefieras.

En el enlace hay fragmentos de código comentado por cada método. Lo he modificado para que devuelva la palabra, si quieres, puede devolver también la longitud.

### 1. Usando bucle `for`

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(' ');
  var longestWord = 0;
  var strValor="";
  for(var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++){
    if(strSplit[i].length > longestWord){
 longestWord = strSplit[i].length;
  strValor=strSplit[i];
     }
  }
  return strValor;
}
var masLarga=findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log(masLarga);
```

### 2. Usando `sort()`

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longestWord = str.split(' ').sort(function(a, b) {   return b.length - a.length; });
  return longestWord[0];
}
var masLarga=findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log(masLarga);
```

### 3. Usando `reduce()`

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longestWord = str.split(' ').reduce(function(longest, currentWord) {
    return currentWord.length > longest.length ? currentWord : longest;
  }, "");
  return longestWord;
}
var masLarga=findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log(masLarga);
```

Comment: Y para la mas corta hay métodos, que no les encuentro...?

Comment: @MiguelEspeso por lo pronto, si usas la **opción 2** con `sort()` invirtiendo el orden de los operadores, te dará la más corta: `return a.length - b.length;`

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono así:

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let orden = str.split(' ').map((a) => a.length)
  let largo = Math.max(...orden)
  return largo
};
console.log(findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es buena, pero no todo el mundo entendería a la primera por qué te funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la manera mas corta, creo.

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  str = str.split(' ').reduce((prev, next) => prev.length > next.length ? prev : next)
  return str.length
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Lee [answer]: explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código, ya que puede que no todos comprendan lo que hace. Tampoco olvides darle formato a tu código. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.